# operator overloading != no match error

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, match, stdlist

In a function I'm checking if a value of a list is or isn't the end of the list:

```
bool Graph::adjacent(const int vertex1, const int vertex2){
return (returnEdge(neighbors(vertex1), vertex2) != neighbors(vertex1).end());
```

In this line neighbors return the adjacency list of a vector:

```
std::list<Edge> Graph::neighbors(int vertex1) const {
return adjacency_list[vertex1];  // returns the list of all the edges
}
```

and returnEdge returns an Edge that is in that list:

```
Edge Graph::returnEdge(std::list<Edge> lista, const int vertex2){
return (*(std::find(lista.begin(), lista.end(), Edge(vertex2, 1))));
}
```

The error rises at the first line of code that I copied here and is:

```
no match for 'operator!=' in '((Graph*)this)->Graph::returnEdge(Graph::neighbors(int) const(vertex1), vertex2) != (&Graph::neighbors(int) const(vertex1))->std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = Edge, _Alloc = std::allocator<Edge>]()'
```

My operator overloading in the file is:

```
bool operator!=(const Edge& e) const 
           { return (e.nextVertex != nextVertex); }
```

I think that I have done my operator overloading wrong or that returnEdge and neighbors().end() doesn't return the same type of variable. How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't think: neighbors(vertex1).end() returns the last element of the list

Comment: `container.end` returns an iterator past the last element. `*container.rbegin` would return the last element.

Comment: @typ1232:  Isn't `container.back()` more idiomatic, though, to get a reference to the last element?  `rbegin()` gives you a full reverse iterator (on containers that support them), while `back()` merely gives you a reference to the last element.   In the original question, though, the real issue is that `find` really _does_ return `end()` if the object isn't found, but `returnEdge` dereferences it—that's undefined!  `returnEdge` ought to return the iterator directly.